# Can CART models be used to select features for a logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, cart

Can I use the features selected from the CART(Classification and Regression Trees) model and take those features and then model the logistic regression using those selected features? Then interpret their betas as CART doesn't provide betas for interpretation. Although CART can be interpretable in itself?

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**
Can I use the features ....

**Answer 1:**
Yes.  There is a nice feature selection tool named [Boruta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boruta/vignettes/inahurry.pdf) that does so well.
Not only can you do it, but it can be a good idea.  Mileage varies, but I have had good results.

**Question 2:**
After I build my logistic regression using the variables can I interpret them?

**Answer 2:**
Yes.  If you take the subset of "important variables" from 1, and use it in a logistic regression then you can interpret the logistic regression.

Should, and how should ... those are different beasties, but the question was "can".

How should you interpret them; how do you do that?  That **how** might be strongly impacted by the difference between the RF and the logistic regression.  "Might be" is a euphemism for will be, and you have to figure out how they are impacted and account for it in your analysis or your results will be problematic in ways you might not expect.

Comment: Worth a warning that doing feature selection before the logistic regression will invalidate the standard errors and p-values from the logistic regression, unless some sort sample splitting is used.